# Hibernate not creating a column

Tags: hibernate, enums

I am using oracle data base with hibernate. I have already set 
`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`
I added `enum` column to the hibernate  model class but the column is not generating.

```
@Column(name="status", columnDefinition="enum('Active','Pending','Cancelled','Suspend')")
public Status status;

enum Status{ Active, Pending, Cancelled, Suspend}
```

Comment: show us the piece of code you added

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Have you looked at the log to see whether there is a failure with the schema migration that is being caught and allowing the application to boot regardless?

Comment: The log says parenthesizes has been missed